# How do I embed messages nicely in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

[image]

This is how my current embedded message looks like, it's really messy and unorganized. How do I make my message look beautiful and organized like this one?

Current code

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="List of webpages you can open",
                      description="eg: `{open yt`, then it gives you a link to youtube :>")
embed.add_field(name="yt", value="https://www.youtube.com/")
embed.add_field(name="reddit", value="https://www.reddit.com/")
embed.add_field(name="ph", value="https://www.pornh- just kidding. There's nothing for that :> (or is there... :>)")
embed.add_field(name="whatsapp", value="https://web.whatsapp.com/")
embed.add_field(name="fb", value="https://www.facebook.com/")
embed.add_field(name="stack", value="https://stackoverflow.com/")
embed.add_field(name="discordbots", value="https://top.gg/")
embed.add_field(name="insta", value="https://www.instagram.com/")
embed.add_field(name="twitter", value="https://twitter.com/")
embed.add_field(name="pin", value="https://www.pinterest.com/")
embed.add_field(name="spotify", value="https://www.spotify.com/my-en/")
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[image]

I'm using discord.py rewrite.

Comment: Can you show your embed code?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Dank Memer is using the embed `description` with [markdown](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/210298617-Markdown-Text-101-Chat-Formatting-Bold-Italic-Underline) instead of using `add_field`

Comment: Sorry I took so long to answer @Deru 
Btw, I didn't know you could insert multiple descriptions derw

Answer (score 1):

If you want each embed field to be on its own line, you have to add inline=False. This could then look like this.

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="Author of the message:", colour=discord.Colour(0x3e038c))

embed.add_field(name=f"Member ID:", value="123456789", inline=False)
embed.add_field(name=f"User Status:", value="online", inline=False)
embed.add_field(name=f"User Creation Time:", value="2017-06-14 19:28:07", inline=False)

await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an image, then you can do:

```py
# all fields are optional
embed = discord.Embed(title="EXAMPLE", description="Something here", \
        URL="https://example.com", colour=discord.Colour.red())
# change this link to an image link, e.g a cdn.discord image
embed.set_image(url="https://imgur.com/image")
```